# dc.js - grouping data using UTC time

Tags: d3.js, datatable, utc, dc.js, crossfilter

I have 2 issues i need help with...

1. When using the range chart to select individual days the data table updates accordingly, but when i extend the range to again include all records i can't seem to select the last day?
2. UTC time issue, i seem to have to change the time to 5pm to have the days display properly if i don't the days seem to shift down a day along with their associated values. See line 85

to be clearer with regards to problem #2

If i use 2010-01-02T00:00:00Z it will map incorrectly to Jan 1st.
if i use 2010-01-02T05:00:00Z it works correctly mapping to jan 2.

I have this posted live on Plunker... see here:

http://plnkr.co/edit/3nPjiE08ZzRXgNmSeym5?p=preview

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Cheers Bruce

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Chart</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.digitalliquid.com/tank/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.digitalliquid.com/tank/dc.css" />

  <style>
    #monthly-volume-chart g.y {
      display: none;
    }

    #logo {
      margin-right: 2em;
      margin-top: 2em;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <!-- <div class="container-fluid"> -->
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div id="monthly-move-chart">
        <strong>Risk History</strong>
        <span class="reset" style="display: none;">range: <span class="filter"></span></span>
        <a class="reset" href="javascript:moveChart.filterAll();volumeChart.filterAll();dc.redrawAll();" style="display: none;">reset</a>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="monthly-volume-chart">
      </div>
      <p class="muted pull-right" style="margin-right: 15px;">select a time range to zoom in</p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div>
        <div class="dc-data-count">
          <span class="filter-count"></span> selected out of <span class="total-count"></span> records | <a href="javascript:dc.filterAll();
          dc.renderAll();">Reset All</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <table class="table table-hover dc-data-table">
      </table>

    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.digitalliquid.com/tank/d3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.digitalliquid.com/tank/crossfilter.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.digitalliquid.com/tank/dc.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.digitalliquid.com/tank/colorbrewer.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    'use strict';

    var moveChart = dc.lineChart('#monthly-move-chart');
    var volumeChart = dc.barChart('#monthly-volume-chart');
    var nasdaqCount = dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count');
    var nasdaqTable = dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table');

    String.prototype.replaceAt = function(index, character) {
      return this.substr(0, index) + character + this.substr(index + character.length);
    }

    // Load Data /Fix date

    d3.json('risk.json', function(data) {
      var dateFormat = d3.time.format.utc("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ");
      data.forEach(function(d) {

      // i seem to have to change the time to 5pm to have the days display properly
      //if i don't the days seem to shift down with their associated values??????
      // comment out the line below to see what i mean

      // change hour in date to 5 pm
        d.date = d.date.replaceAt(12, "5");


        d.dd = dateFormat.parse(d.date);
        d.month = d3.time.month(d.dd);
        d.day = d3.time.day(d.dd);
          d.risk = +d.risk; // coerce to number
      });

      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));


      //  ### Create Crossfilter Dimensions and Groups******************

      var ndx = crossfilter(data);
      var totalReadings = ndx.size();
      var all = ndx.groupAll();

      // var brush = d3.svg.brush();

      // Dimension by full date
      var dateDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.dd;
      });

      // Dimension by risk
      var riskdimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.risk;
      });

      // Dimension by day
      var daydim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
        return d.day;
      });

      var mygroup = daydim.group().reduce(
        function(p, v) {
          ++p.days;
          //   p.total += (v.open + v.close) / 2;
          //    p.avg = Math.round(p.total / p.days);
          //  return v.risk;
          p.risk = v.risk
          return p;
        },
        function(p, v) {
          --p.days;
          //   p.total -= (v.open + v.close) / 2;
          //   p.avg = p.days ? Math.round(p.total / p.days) : 0;
          // return v.risk;
          p.risk = v.risk
          return p;
        },
        function() {
          return {
            risk: 0,

          };
        }
      );

      //### Define Chart Attributes

      moveChart
        .renderArea(true)
        .width(960)
        .height(200)
        .transitionDuration(1000)
        .margins({
          top: 30,
          right: 50,
          bottom: 25,
          left: 40
        })
        .dimension(daydim)
        .group(mygroup, 'Risk')
        .mouseZoomable(true)
        .rangeChart(volumeChart)
        .y(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
        .x(d3.time.scale().domain([data[0].dd, data[data.length - 1].dd]))
        .round(d3.time.day.round)
        .xUnits(d3.time.days)
        .renderHorizontalGridLines(true)

      // ##### Legend   ----------------------------------------------------------

      .legend(dc.legend().x(880).y(10).itemHeight(13).gap(5))
        .brushOn(false)
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
          return d.value.risk;

        })

      //  #### Volume Chart  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      volumeChart

        .width(960)
        .height(40)
        .margins({
          top: 0,
          right: 50,
          bottom: 20,
          left: 40
        })

 .dimension(daydim)
        .group(mygroup, 'Risk')

       .centerBar(true)
       .gap(1)
       .x(d3.time.scale().domain([data[0].dd, data[data.length - 1].dd]))
       .round(d3.time.day.round)
       .alwaysUseRounding(true)
       .xUnits(d3.time.days)

  .valueAccessor(function(d) {
          return d.value.risk;

        });







      //#### Data Count ***********************************
      nasdaqCount /* dc.dataCount('.dc-data-count', 'chartGroup'); */
      //   dc.dataCount(".dc-data-count")
      // dc.dataCount("#monthly-move-chart")
        .dimension(ndx)
        .group(all);

      // .html({
      //   some: '<strong>%filter-count</strong> selected out of <strong>%total-count</strong> records' +
      //     ' | <a href=\'javascript:dc.filterAll(); dc.renderAll();\'\'>Reset All</a>',
      //   all: 'All records selected. Please click on the graph to apply filters.'
      // });







      //#### Data Table
      nasdaqTable /* dc.dataTable('.dc-data-table', 'chartGroup') */
        .dimension(dateDimension)

      .group(function(d) {
        var format = d3.format('02d');
        return d.dd.getFullYear() + '/' + format((d.dd.getMonth() + 1));
      })

      .size(100)

      .columns(['date', 'risk', ])

      .sortBy(function(d) {
          return d.dd;
        })
        // (_optional_) sort order, `default = d3.ascending`
        .order(d3.ascending)
        // (_optional_) custom renderlet to post-process chart using [D3](http://d3js.org)
        .on('renderlet', function(table) {
          table.selectAll('.dc-table-group').classed('info', true);
        });

      dc.renderAll();

    });
  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Problem 1. was solved using nice(d3.time.day,[2]) , still dealing with problem#2

Answer (score 1):

By default all times will be interpreted in the local time zone.

If you want to group your data using UTC time, you should use the [UTC versions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals#interval_utc) of the d3 time interval utilities.

So, everywhere you use `d3.time.days` that should be `d3.time.days.utc`, etc.

We use these in the dc.js Jasmine tests to ensure the tests run consistently in any time zone.

It will probably take some iteration to shake out all the places that are assuming the local time zone. I have fixed a few more in my fork of your plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/qX5WvAeLxaO6kq6tqJ4C?p=preview

First, you probably also need to use `d3.time.day.utc` (note the singular form) in your dimension function, instead of reading the `.dd` field, which will use the local time zone:

```
  // Dimension by day
  var daydim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d3.time.day.utc(d.dd);
  });
```

(This may not matter in your case, if the data is not more granular than a day, but it will matter if you need to group multiple times within a day.)

Next, anything that prints the dates is going to screw them up again. So, the title function:

```
  moveChart
    .title(function(d) { return d.key.toUTCString() + ': ' + d.value; })
```

Next, the filter printer. Here you probably want to use d3 time formatting, I printed the details in order to debug the brushing issue mentioned below:

```
    .filterPrinter(function(f) {
      return f[0][0].toUTCString() + ' - ' + f[0][1].toUTCString()
    });
```

Finally, even though the chart is showing the whole last day, you have actually set the end of the range to the beginning of the first day, so it can't include the last data point.

There is probably a bug in dc.js here (or some confusing features), but we'll ignore that and just add a second to the end of the range:

```
var endDate = new Date(data[data.length - 1].dd);
endDate.setSeconds(endDate.getSeconds()+1)

    .x(d3.time.scale.utc().domain([data[0].dd, endDate]))
```

Comment: That helped, still having issue with last record simply not showing up in datatable, if you see the plunk below you will see i cannot select the last record using the rangefinder, also why are UTC dates showing up with a 7pm time signature when points rolled over on the line chart?

http://plnkr.co/edit/qXQddzUu3gMsNBGnPSDm?p=preview

Comment: There were a couple more places you needed to specify UTC, since it defaults to local **everywhere**. I'll add those above.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon for your attention to this, i am wondering why i cannot keep this as i "think" it is calculated in the previous foreach function.

{
  var daydim = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
   return d.day;
  });}

Comment: Sure, guessed I missed that. As long as it works. ;)

Comment: 2 last observations:


1. The filterPrinter function is showing the correct hour 00:00:00 but in GMT time, i was expecting it to have "GMT -0500 (Eastern Standard Time)" at the end??


2. The title command is showing "Sat, 02 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT: [object Object]" on rollover, again i would like to see something like "Sat, 02 Jan 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)"

Cheers Bruce

Comment: From javascript reference... they say GMT and UTC are the same but they are not...

"The toUTCString() method converts a Date object to a string, according to universal time.Tip: The Universal Coordinated Time (UTC) is the time set by the World Time Standard.Note: UTC time is the same as GMT time."

Until 1972, Greenwich Mean Time (also known as Zulu time) was the same as Universal Time (UT) The difference between GMT and UTC
Since then, GMT is no longer a time standard. Today, Greenwich Mean Time is only the name of a time zone.

Comment: But you specified your dates in UTC in the json with `Z` so they are midnight UTC not EST, right? I think I've provided enough help to set you on your path.